# Invalid value used as weak map key (nextJS & Strapi)

Tags: json, typescript, next.js, strapi, weakmap

When mapping my fetched data in nextjs it is throwing the error bellow. Data is fetched succesfully, so that's not the problem. The code worked before but when I added new data into strapi it broke.

```
<div className="overflow-x-auto relative rounded">
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead className='text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400'>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Onr</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Saddle Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Seat Size</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Colour</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Customer</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Order Date</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Date Updated</th>
                        <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">Zadelpasser</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        {
                        tempOrders.map((entry) => (
                            <DataEntry
                                key={entry.id.toString()}
                                id={entry.id}
                                saddlename={entry.attributes.saddle_type.data.attributes.Name}
                                seatsize={entry.attributes.order_attributes.SeatSize}
                                colour={entry.attributes.order_attributes.Colour}
                                status={entry.attributes.order_status.data.attributes.status_name}
                                customer={entry.attributes.order_attributes.Customer}
                                createdAt={DateTime.now(entry.attributes.createdAt).toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')}
                                updatedAt={DateTime.now(entry.attributes.updatedAt).toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')}
                                passer={entry.attributes.saddle_fitter_id.data.attributes.username}
                            />
                        ))}      
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
```

```
TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key
    at WeakMap.set (<anonymous>)
    at attemptResolveElement (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1153:52)
    at resolveModelToJSON (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1620:53)
    at Array.toJSON (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1081:40)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at processModelChunk (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:163:36)
    at retryTask (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1823:50)
    at performWork (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1856:33)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1257:40)
    at scheduleWork (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:52:25)
```

I looked into the documentation, but found nothing related to this issue.